# MVC:Using 2 models in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 tables in my database i.e Company and Branches.So,ideally a company can have more than one branches.Using entity framework I had added the model class for both.In the view page of Create Company,I have a section of adding multiple branches to that specific company.Specifically,it's having a div which is made for adding one branch.After that,there is a link to add more branches.When user will click on the link,a similar div will open.How can I fulfill the same task?

Model Class:

```
namespace Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            this.Branches = new HashSet<Branches>();
        }

        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string QuickInfo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Branches> Branches { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create View:

```
@model Models.Company

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company"))
                    {  
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name,null)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.QuickInfo,null)
}
<div>
<a href="#" >Add Branch</a>
                        <h3>Branch</h3>
@Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Branches.Add() /*what to do here*/
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't very well suited to very open-ended *"How do I do this?"* questions without a huge amount of information up-front, which you haven't provided. Put in as much effort into asking the question as you would hope someone would put into answering it. Give us diagrams, code, attempted solutions and so on to help us help you. It's useful to provide broken or pseudo-code so that we can see your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewModel` to use multiple models in a view

For eg:

Let's say you want to use 2 models viz., ModelA and ModelB in your view.

```
ModelA
{
     public int PropA { get; set; } 
     public int PropB { get; set; } 
}

ModelB
{
     public int PropC { get; set; } 
     public int PropD { get; set; } 
}
```

Now to use both models in a single view, you can create a single ViewModel

For e.g.,

```
ModelC
{
     public int PropX { get; set; } 
     public int PropY { get; set; } 
     public List<ModelA> ListOfModelA { get; set; }
     public List<ModelB> ListofModelB { get; set; }
}
```

Thus now your ModelC will have list of both ModelA and ModelB plus it have its own properties and can be used in a single view.